# Python on a Mac - Can't find File

Tags: python

Someone wrote Python Code for me but didn't realize I was on a Mac.

I am getting the following error:

```
Last login: Thu Jan 23 08:14:39 on ttys001
nraidervlan10:~ nraider$ cd '/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code/Master.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
paths CWD=/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code, CPD=/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code/Master.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code/Master.py", line 114, in main
    playerLists = loadFiles(CPD + "PlayerFiles/")
  File "/Users/nraider/Downloads/Ten-code/Master.py", line 44, in loadFiles
    except FileNotFoundError:
NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined
nraidervlan10:Ten-code nraider$
```

I assumed it was a Path issue and modified the code below for the directories from \ to /.  But there still seems to be an issue.  The relevant code is below. Any ideas?

============================================================

```
import csv
import os
import sys
import random
import time

CWD = os.getcwd()



#CPD = CWD.split('Ten-code')[0]+'Ten-code\\'
CPD = CWD.split('Ten-code')[0]+'Ten-code/'




#sys.path.append(CPD+'Modules\\Player_Class')
sys.path.append(CPD+'Modules/Player_Class')




#sys.path.append(CPD+'Modules\\Court_Class')
sys.path.append(CPD+'Modules/Court_Class')



print("paths CWD=%s, CPD=%s" % (CWD, CPD))



from playerClass import *
from courtClass import *

def loadFiles(directory):
    fileList = os.listdir(directory)
    playerLists = []
    for file in fileList:
        filePath = directory + file
        try:
            reader = csv.reader(open(filePath, 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig", errors="ignore"))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File \'%s\' not found" % filePath)
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError` doesn't exist in Python 2.x; are you sure you are using Python 3?

Comment: Please read the error message: `NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined` - it's coming from Python itself, and it's not about a file not being found, it's about a name missing from the global namespace. As suggested above, you should run this with Python 3

Comment: Run `/usr/bin/pythonw -v` to find the python version

Comment: Though Python only tries to look up `FileNotFoundError` if an exception is, in fact, raised, so there's probably still a question here once the correct version of Python is used.

Comment: Thanks all.  It looks like I am running V3.8.